# Change file location for Android Studio

Tags: file, android-studio

So, I just started using Android Studio. I am using windows 7 64bit on my main SSD. When I installed the IDE, I have the SDK and Android Studio saved on a secondary drive. Now I noticed that Android Studio added 3 other folders in the "Personal Folder" in my main SSD (.android, .AndriodStudio, .gradle).

Anyone know how to give these guys a different destination so I can save space on my main hard drive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copy those folders to wherever you want. But once you copy do the following steps.

1.) Open Windows explorer and right click on computer and select properties. In the control panel home that opened select advanced system settings in the left pane. Then select environment variables under advanced tab in the system properties window.

2.) Add a new user variable with name 'ANDROID_AVD_HOME' and value as path to /.android/avd/

3.) Similarly set GRADLE environment variables. This link might help - http://www.gradle.org/installation

4.) Start Android Studio - it will ask if you want to import config file. Give location to /.AndroidStudio/config

I hope this should work fine.

Comment: Worked beautifully! My hard drive and I thank you. Also where did you find the variables and path values? Does this work for all files?

Comment: It should work similarly for all files ideally although there might be exceptions. I was having some different trouble working with Studio and figured out the Path Name for android home in the official google forum.

Comment: Got error: Cannot find file 'D:\Android\.AndroidStudio3.0\config\settings.jar' when importing config