# Android Studio pointing at wrong user directory

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.0

On my machine I have two user directories, one local on `C:\Users\Username\`, and another on a network path `\\networkName\Home\Username`.

Although Android studio was stored in `C:\Program Files`, and the SDK folder was set to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`, Android Studio itself insists on using the network home, saving all local application data there, and as there's no space on this directory, causing Android Studio to throw constant No enough space on the disk exceptions, or file not found.

Is there an environment variable, or registry key I need to change to get it to point at the right folder?

Comment: Could you open the settings and check what path is it using?

Comment: What path it is using for what? If you mean the SDK it's in the correct path (`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`). If you mean something else, where would I find that?

Comment: Check `File -> Settings -> Appearance & behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK`.

Comment: Like I said, it's pointing at `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Comment: The answer might be found in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435084/change-file-location-for-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

To change the Environment variable follow the steps by @tacticurv:

1.) Open Windows explorer and right click on computer and select properties. In the control panel home that opened select advanced system settings in the left pane. Then select environment variables under advanced tab in the system properties window.

2.) Add a new user variable with name 'ANDROID_AVD_HOME' and value as path to /.android/avd/

3.) Similarly set GRADLE environment variables. This link might help - http://www.gradle.org/installation

4.) Start Android Studio - it will ask if you want to import config file. Give location to /.AndroidStudio/config